# How to open browser after the run button clicked in Intellij Idea CE?

Tags: java, browser, intellij-idea

I have simple task in Intellij Idea CE, after clicking Run(Shift+F10), browser must open some page, for example `http://localhost:8080`. How to do that?
I can't find reliable option in Edit configurations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the "Edit configurations" there's a checkbox for "Start browser" under the "Server" tab in a server configuration.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for quick response, but I am using Community Edition, don't have Server tab.

Comment: @RinatTainov Then I don't think the option exists; since the CE doesn't do web development, there's no reason for it to automatically open a browser.

Comment: @RinatTainov Why not just keep a browser window open? Doesn't seem like a big deal.

Comment: it was just good idea to have multiple run settings that can open multiple pages of project, never mind @Dave Newton, thanks! Maybe, it has some option to do some callback after run event?

Comment: @RinatTainov Ah, I see. Not sure if there's an IDE event mechanism--I'd probably consider just writing some shell scripts and not run it from inside the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

You can add various steps to be executed before launch in the `Edit Configurations...` window. Just add step "External tool", create a new tool pointing to the browser exe, and pass the desired URL (like http://localhost.8080) as a parameter.

If you use Chrome as a browser, you may want to use [Only One extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/only-one/ffkdlcmdgpagmbokblekleghfkjgpjdo/related?hl=en) to reuse the existing Tab/Window with the URL when it is already open.

Comment: Note: There seems to be some complication - it worked for me at first, however later my debugger started to attach to the chrome.exe instead of the application being debugged and I was not able to get it working again.

Comment: These steps are done before building the application, but the questions is regarding to open the browser after building the application. If one could add a whole run configuration "Open URL" one could add the build of the application as step before that there. But I cannot find a way to do that.